# Winter Bash error - cannot get hat: Hero of time

Tags: support, winter-bash-2017

So I notice that we now have Winter Bash 2017.

I tried to get the [Hero of time](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/hero-of-time) hat, but it didn't work. Is this an error?

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47868078/check-before-delete-or-just-delete-row/47868392#47868392) at 7.00 PM GMT+7 on Stack Overflow for `Hero of time hat`.

Thanks for any advice to fix or to send a support ticket of this case.

Comment: you also need an +1 score for the question to qualify

Comment: @Memor-X thank you. Do you have any reference doc/policy to this requirement?

Comment: yeh, was just looking for it. [here it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats/304341#comment990095_304341). and the following comment links to a better meta question

Comment: @Memor-X a, thank you for searching that. I can't find that in their offical document, and search but can't find that too.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Thanks for that [Naming guideline](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)